# How many Gods are In Hindu Culture?

Tags: gods

There are lot of gods and saint in Hindu culture . But how many ?

Comment: About List of gurus and saints in Hinduism - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hindu_gurus_and_saints

Comment: gods is an imprecise English term to easily confused with God. All orthodox Hindus (Vedantists being a more precise term) believe in only one God. The correct term you are referring to is deva and the literal translation is 'shining one'. Devas are titles like governor or chief minister. Jivas are given the title for a kapla, or cycle, after which they are reborn here. Don't confuse devas with the One God, Iswara.

Comment: How many names do you remember -- is a subjective question and not in sync with community guidelines. Please edit accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

> There are 33 Gods. It is mentioned many times in Vedas .  This
> transition from 33 to 330 million came after Upanishadic Age.
> Upanishads taught that Ultimate reality is a single supreme soul
> Brahman.  The count went to millions in an attempt to poetically
> express the infinitude of the universe, to capture the all-pervading
> reality. This is how 330 million gods made sense.
>
> [Source quora](https://www.quora.com/Where-does-the-count-of-330-million-Hindu-Gods-come-from)

There are 33 different gods. Shivji, Vishnuji and Brahmaji are three major Hindu Gods.

Comment: No, 33 million gods came when some people translated the original word `koti` as crores.

Comment: 330 crore is nothing but 3300 millions which is equivalent to 3.3 billion.